# how to subtract 5 mins time from this "4:30 pm" string

Tags: c#, timespan

I have a problem declaring a time variable with a value of 5 minutes and I want to use this variable to subtract to 4:30 pm string. But I don't know how do I declare that variable. Is there an easy way to subtract that 4:30 pm string?

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    AMSetTime = (reader["AMOutTime"].ToString());
    PMSetTime = (reader["PMOutTime"].ToString());
}
TimeSpan timeUpdateCount = DateTime.Parse(PMSetTime).TimeOfDay;
TimeSpan minusFiveMinutes(00:05); //Error here
```

Answer (score 2):

We define timespan of minutes with the following way:

```
TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
```

Then you can use this timespan as you wish.

Specifically, in your case you can try the following:

```
TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
TimeSpan timeUpdateCount = DateTime.Parse(PMSetTime).TimeOfDay-interval;
```

Comment: thank you so much for help... You save one of the function of my system. thank you